# Angular2 Passing Auth Token to another Service

Tags: angular

I have the below code where I am getting the Auth Token,

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {


   @Input() isValid:boolean=false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
  auth_token:string;
  /** sign in user */

  login(username, password) {

      this.req = this.http.post('URL for Authenticaion', {
      "username": username, 
      "password": password 
    })
        .subscribe(
              result => {
               console.log(result);
                this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);




                    }

}
```

Now I want to pass this token to another service which will retrieve all the data. The issue I am facing is result.auth_token is local to this current block so its not recognized outside of it.
How do I return its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use Subject/BehaviorSubject which will act as observer and observable. You can emit the token and catch in the another service. Here is the code

In AuthenticationService:

private modelAlertEvent = new Subject<any>();
public modelAlertEventObservable = this.modelAlertEvent.asObservable();
this.modelAlertEvent.next(token);

In Another Service

this.modelsubscribe = this.authservice.modelAlertEventObservable.subscribe(token=>{
    console.log(token);
});
```

Comment: Do I really need an Observable here? Cant the other service just access that var like this.authservice.auth_token?

Comment: You can access it, if you are accessing other service after user authentication. Because User authenication will have a delay for HTTP request to complete.